# Hidden attributes didn't hide the file completely?

Tags: c#, file

Let say a file has attribute `Hidden` but when I unchecked the **Hide protected operating system files** from folder options file is visible.

```
Io.File.SetAttributes("File.txt",IO.FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You can ask explorer to show hidden files regardless of these settings. You can't *truly* hide a file, you can only signal to "most" applications that you don't want it shown, but those programs can still show the file just fine and this includes Windows Explorer.

Comment: "How to resolve this problem", well, if Windows Explorer shows these files with this setting, and is meant to, then you can't resolve it. The file will be shown, nothing you can do about this. If you suspect Windows Explorer has a bug regarding this you should check if there is any documentation about what it should do and then possibly file a bug using Microsoft Connect.

Comment: Protected OS files are super-hidden, they also have FileAttributes.System turned on.

Comment: But there are some applications which completely hides a folder.there should be a solution for this to hide the file completely.

Comment: If you're relying on hiding files like this as some sort of security or software protection, then you're going to have a bad time. Just leave the file visible and instead rely on something like encryption perhaps.

Comment: Files can be hidden only from ordinary user. They cannot be hide from the administrator. However, the user may encrypt your files so nobody can read it.

Answer (score 0):

From the point that you want to hide a file and never be seen by allowing to display hidden files and folders, you can restrict directory access which will not let you open the directory in the first place. This piece of code can be put to use:

```
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity;
bool modifiedFlag;

dirSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(yourFolderPath);

foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in dirSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier)))
{
      // Secure file to not allow any modification actions by user
      dirSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add
                                   , new FileSystemAccessRule(rule.IdentityReference, FileSystemRights.Modify, AccessControlType.Deny)
                                   , out modifiedFlag);
}

Directory.SetAccessControl(yourFolderPath, dirSecurity);
```

Doing this you will block user from even opening the folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there comes the user access issue here when I use the administrator account i can change the access control without any effort.

Comment: Well, it will take some effort to open up the access even for an Admin. Admin would not see the option to change the access directly as there will be inherited accesses as well.